# Improve slow initial page load of SPA when using authorization code flow

Tags: angular, performance, oauth, single-page-application, keycloak

I have a Single Page Application written in Angular that uses Keycloak and the authorization code flow for login.

The flow works for logging in, but it increases the initial page load time from about 500ms which is good for a large Angular application, to about 2500-4000ms. I've had users close the tab and report that the site is down because it loads so slowly.

Looking at the network tab, the increased load time is due to the 6 calls to my keycloak server caused by initializing keycloak before the page is displayed.

What can I do to speed this up? In terms of hardware, Keycloak is running on Google Compute and its Postgres DB is hosted on CloudSQL.

```
// Init method in keycloak-js, called from the AppModule.
keycloak.init(options?: KeycloakOptions)

// Network traffic added by auth flow
step1.html
step2.html
login.status-iframe.html
init?....
auth?...
token
account
```

--

Edit:
I've switched the frontend library to `angular-auth-oidc-client` with the current config.

```
{
  stsServer: 'https://<server>',
  redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
  clientId: '<client-id>',
  scope: 'openid offline_access profile email roles',
  responseType: 'code',
  silentRenew: true,
  useRefreshToken: true,
  renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 30,
};
```

Comment: This is most likely an issue on the server side, not on the browser side.

Comment: Well the page displays when the flow is done, so that's on the app. But the actual flow is indeed pretty slow. The time the flow takes is taken up in part by work on the server and in part by the 6 roundtrips. Btw this is a clean install of Keycloak.

Comment: I would start with the step that takes the longest and start debugging from there. Currently as is, the question doesn't have enough information to answer. The issue could be from anything. You need to pinpoint where the slow spot(s) are, and then you can ask a question or two about each of the slow spots.

Comment: There are different approaches to the situation. As an example (but not a suggestion), Firebase auth is lightning fast and makes no calls. Without knowing, I'd guess that it uses an implicit flow and stores credentials in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You need to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
It is not clear which `keycloakOptions` are you using.

2.) I can assume (even when I don't see `keycloakOptions`), that you are not using the optimal flow for SPA. I would use authorization code with PKCE, so option can be (of course these options may not suitable for your use case, because I don't know your code, but it is a good starting point):

```
{ 
  url: <URL>,
  realm: <REALM>,
  clientId: <CLIENT_ID>,
  onLoad: 'login-required',
  promiseType: 'native', 
  checkLoginIframe: false, 
  pkceMethod: 'S256'
}
```

Anyway, I would recommend to read doc of used library to have idea what is offering: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_javascript_adapter

Comment: Added options. I've read the chapter on the JavaScript Adapter but unfortunately it only explains how things work, now how to create a good enough user experience -- I suspect it's not possible with that library.

Comment: @Martin01478 did you try config, which I have suggested? Why you are not using PKCE flow? But you are using default setup, which is more suitable for old school web app and not SPA. Library offers many options for many use cases. You as developer should be aware of the best design and then just configure used tool/lib for that. That's IMHO out of the scope of used lib (Keycloak in this particular case). If default setup will be more suitable for SPA devs, then web devs will be complaining about poor user experience. I would recommend to spend more time to learn about OIDC/OAuth flows first.